# Want to add multiple contact for sharing information in windows phone 8.1 app developement

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, window

I am very new in windows phone application development.
I am developing contact sharing app in which once a user clicks on Contact Push  radio button as mentioned in the below :

```
            
            SMS
            Bluetooth
            Email
            Contact Push
            Button x:Name="sendContact_Btn"  Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Send" Height="65" Width="160" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="sendContact_Btn_Click"  />
```

A popup box should be open in which I am able to add multiple number to whom I want to send the information.

Platform - WIndows phone 8.1
XAML and C#

Can you please someone help me how to create a popup layout having contact details information.